# How is the CDF ("pgamma") of The Average of 10 Samples from Two Gammas Derived?

Tags: r, average, p-value, cdf, mixture-model

### Case I: One Gamma ( I can do this! )

```
shape<-shape*10

scale<-scale/10

p_value_average_of_10_draws<-1-pgamma(q=average_of_10_draws, shape=shape, scale=scale, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
```

### Case II: Two Gammas (I can't do this!)

```
shape_A<-shape_A*10

scale_A<-scale_A/10

shape_B<-shape_B*10

scale_B<-scale_B/10

pgamma_A_and_B <-

pgamma(q=average_of_10_draws, shape=shape_A, scale=scale_A, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)*weight_A

+

pgamma(q=average_of_10_draws, shape=shape_B, scale=scale_B, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)*(1-weight_A)

p_value_average_of_10_draws<-1-pgamma_A_and_B
```

But this is just wrong!

Because it assumes that all ten draws will be taken from just one of A or B!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is well-known rule how to make probability density function (PDF) of sum of two independent random variates (Z = X+Y) with their own PDFs

```
PDF(z) = S PDF_x(t) * PDF_y(z-t) dt
```

where `S` is integration sign. Not sure there is a generic expression for sum of gammas with any parameters. There are packages in **R** which does numeric convolution in the integral above.

Is that what you want?

UPDATE

## K-S example test of two gammas

```
library(ggplot2)

fitted.pdf <- function(x, w, a1, s1, a2, s2) {
    w*dgamma(x, shape = a1, scale = s1) + (1.0-w)*dgamma(x, shape = a2, scale = s2)
}

fitted.cdf <- function(x, w, a1, s1, a2, s2) {
    w*pgamma(x, shape = a1, scale = s1) + (1.0-w)*pgamma(x, shape = a2, scale = s2)
}

p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x))
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) fitted.pdf(x, w=0.6, a1=1.0, s1=1.0, a2=0.8, s2=1.2))
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) fitted.cdf(x, w=0.6, a1=1.0, s1=1.0, a2=0.8, s2=1.2))
p <- p + xlim(0.0, 4.0) + ylim(0.0, 1.0)
print(p)

# sample 100 from exponential
x <- rexp(100)

# K-S test
q <- ks.test(x, y=function(x) fitted.cdf(x, w=0.6, a1=1.0, s1=1.0, a2=0.8, s2=1.2))
print(q)
```

Comment: I see your point, that could be too complicated. Let me restate the problem this way: There are two sets of data. I fit a two gamma mixture model to the first. What is the probability that the second set of data could have been generated by the pdf composed of those two weighted gammas?

Comment: @rwinkel2000 So, you build numerical PDF and fit it with something like `w_1*Gamma(a1,b1) + w2*Gamma(a2,b2)` ? (With `w1+w2=1` condition)

Comment: That's right. Now how to I calculate the probability that the second set of data could have been generated by that numerical PDF?

Comment: @rwinkel2000 There are many ways to do that, one being histogram comparison. Another one which I like is to do Q-Q plot, which is basically CDF-to-CDF comparison. I have no **R** code, but take a look at very good description here: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/advanced_graphs/q-q_plots.html

Comment: @rwinkel2000 another link http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/qqplot.htm

Comment: Which in your opinion is better: qq or k-s? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html I'm looking at this ks link and trying to think of how I should represent a fitted mixture model (as opposed to a single pdf model) into this requirement: "y...either a numeric vector of data values, or a character string naming a cumulative distribution function or an actual cumulative distribution function such as pnorm."

Comment: @rwinkel2000 There are many tests which could be used. Q-Q vs K-S are of different leagues. Q-Q is more of exploratory analysis, to visually verify if there are areas of disagreement. K-S is more of how to quantify difference, computing "distance" between distributions. You could use any or both

Comment: I need an actual p-value so I'd like to use K-S, but will the R implementation ks.test(...) let me test against a "custom" pdf? That's my final puzzle.

Comment: @rwinkel2000 it should. I put some code in the update, test exponential distribution vs two weighted gammas

Comment: @rwinkel2000 Apparently, there is a code in **R** which does Q-Q comparison of smapled vs theoretical/fitted distribution. Take a look at http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/lattice/qqmath